# What's the recommended limit for number of info-hashes allowed to be scraped?

Tags: bittorrent

I'm realising HTTP scraping for multiple hashes.
Though I know scraping is not widely used by clients (the only one I know is Transmission, tell me if you know more), what could be a reasonable limit of info-hashes for the scraper to process and response?

For an UDP tracker it's 74 at a time.

Currently my idea is 10.

What should be the optimal cache ttl for scrape responses before hitting db for renewed statistics?

While scraping do we have to give full v2 info hashes in bencoded files array or truncated ones?

P.S.
Also is it a good idea to record peer's listening port instead of the one which is being sent in &port GET parameter to help some peers behind a NAT?

Answer (score 0):

> what could be a reasonable limit of info-hashes for the scraper to process and response?

Accepting and processing a TCP/HTTP connection already costs some resources. So it's reasonable to support as infohashes as long as it only adds marginal costs on top of that.
How much that is depends on your tracker implementation. If you're keeping all the data in efficient in-memory data structures (since peer lists are mostly ephemeral anyway) and don't need to query an external database it should be possible to look that up in microseconds.

Benchmark your tracker and find a point where the additional cost per infohash is still small compared to the cost of a connection.

> What should be the optimal cache ttl for scrape responses before hitting db for renewed statistics?

As I wrote above, you really shouldn't be hitting a DB at all. But if you do anyway then you probably want to adjust the TTL dynamically based on swarm behavior. A new torrent will likely be a lot more dynamic than one that has existed for a few days.

> While scraping do we have to give full v2 info hashes in bencoded files array or truncated ones?

A *tracker* should be oblivious to torrents. All it sees is hashes, ips and ports. So it won't know anything about v1 or v2 which means it has to use the truncated hashes.

> Though I know scraping is not widely used by clients (the only one I know is Transmission, tell me if you know more),

libtorrent supports scraping so I'd expect any client based on it supporting it too.

> P.S. Also is it a good idea to record peer's listening port instead of the one which is being sent in &port GET parameter to help some peers behind a NAT?

This doesn't seem relevant at all to scrapes.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, the last question about the port was more like an announcer's question, I forgot to add a reference.

Comment: Also - is scraping a real thing these days? I thought this helped before the introduction of interval parameter to get more information about peers during download, and also there is DHT these days, what is the current value of scraping?

Comment: scrapes are used by clients to display statistics about torrents that are currently not active and to make scheduling decisions.

Comment: Got it, and what about the port question for the announcer?

Comment: Could you please collaborate on this matter?

Comment: make a separate question to keep things focused, since this one was about scraping.